# Power Automate Convert File from CSV to XLSX

Tags: excel, sharepoint, xlsx, power-automate, office-scripts

Good Day!!    Got a problem in Power Automate that I have played with for days now... With that, I am a hobby programmer and an accountant by day.

I am attempting to use MS Power Automate to grab a CSV file from an SFTP site and save it to my SharePoint site as an XLSX.   I can get it to convert to xls....but the next step in the flow is going to be to run an Excel Office Script on the file.  It needs to be in xlsx format for that to work...

So when I run the flow...it shows it works. But you are unable to open the file while it is in xlsx format.  Again no problem in xls.   I have researched to see if I can do this in two steps in PowerAutomate...first to xls them run another process to convert that to xlsx, but have been unsuccessful in finding the solution.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated...GREATLY

[image: Picture of my Flow as it stands now]

Comment: Create a blank Excel file somewhere on your SP instance.  Copy that file into the location you want with a new name and then fill it using he Office Script.  You need a blank Excel workbook and that's the way to do it, there is no create workbook activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to use another Office script to turn it into an xlsx.

Below is a Microsoft Learn doc with that approach:
[Convert CSV files to Excel workbooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/scripts/resources/samples/convert-csv)